# Create download url for Dynamically Generated file on server

Tags: c#, apache-flex, dynamic, download

I've got a flex web app that, when the user pushes a button, makes a service call to the server.  Inside the service call, a custom exporter object is created and in that object a PDF file is generated using iTextSharp.  I want to be able to generate a url to the file location in that service call and pass it back to the flex app to use with FileReference.download().  The service call simply gets the object that holds the data needed for the PDF from an id passed to the function, creates the exporter object and sends back the file path.  Inside the exporter object's exporting function it looks like so:

```
        this.ObjectId = object.Id;
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/temp/TestBoth.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        MyPageEventHandler e = new MyPageEventHandler(this.ObjectId);
        writer.PageEvent = e;
        doc.Open();
        this.ExportThingOne(object, true, doc, writer);
        doc.NewPage();
        this.ExportThingTwo(object, true, doc);

        doc.Close();

        System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
        string serverPath = page.Server.MapPath("C:/temp/TestBoth.pdf");
        return serverPath;
```

The file is generated perfectly at C:/temp/TestBoth.pdf on my local machine (only testing things locally before pushing to an actual server), however I get an exception thrown when I attempt `page.Server.MapPath("C:/temp/TestBoth.pdf");`.  Am I missing a step to set the server of the page to something or is there another way to go about getting the server path?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the web app locally with the debugger, you're using your own credentials to identify against the operating system. When you then deploy it to the server, it runs under whatever identity your application pool is set to run as - usually network service or IIS_USR. None of these users has access to the c:/Temp/ folder, which is why you're getting the exception. Either change the folder permissions(and preferably save within you web applications own folder instead of a shared temp folder) or save to a different location, such as a varbinary field in a database.

Comment: I've never worked with saving a file to a "varbinary field in a database", could you perhaps give an example of such a thing?